# GnuPlot draw line between points with different color for the same dataset

Tags: gnuplot, visualization

I have a dataset that represents the points while creating a circle (multiple circles), like so: [image]

```
    gnuplot <<-EOF
        set autoscale
        plot "$file"  w lp 
EOF
```

I would like to express the point creation timestamps with colors, so let's give a number to every color, starting from `red` to `blue`, from 1 to `SAMPLE_COUNT`; I need to draw lines between points:

- #point_0 -> color: 1 -> #point_1
- #point_1 -> color: 2 -> #point_2

and so on. In the end, I'd like to get something like:

[image]

Can we make this with GnuPlot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with variable linecolor (lc) and palette z (check `help lc`). You are using the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`), i.e. basically the line index, as range for the color palette.
If you don't want to see the colorbox add a line `unset colorbox`.

**Script:**

```
### variable line color via palette z
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot [0:4*pi] '+' u ($1*cos(x)):($1*sin(x)) w table
unset table

set size ratio -1
set palette defined (0 "red", 1 "orange", 2 "yellow", 3 "green", 4 "cyan", 5 "blue")

plot $Data u 1:2:0 w lp pt 7 lc palette z
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Result is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu5Aa.png Thank you.